# ddply colSums and count of column together

Tags: r, plyr

I'm new to R and have pieced together this syntax below based on other helpful suggestions here on the StackOverflow.  I'm trying to sum the column called "COMBINED HOURS" and get a COUNT of the column called DOC_LINE_NUM grouped by the column DOC_NUM.

So for each DOC_NUM, calculate a sum COMBINED_HOURS, and show a COUNT of DOC_LINE_NUM.

The syntax below works fine to get a column sum of COMBINED_HOURS but how do I incorporate a COUNT logic into this syntax for DOC_LINE_NUM?

Thank you.

```
train2 <- ddply(train, c("WEEKNUM", "DOC_NUM", "DOC_LINE_NUM", "SHORT_DATE","CUST_CODE", "OP_CODE", "JOB_TP_CODE"), function(x) colSums(x[c("COMBINED_HOURS")]))

# Sample data

WEEKNUM DOC_NUM DOC_LINE_NUM SHORT_DATE CUST_CODE  OP_CODE JOB_TP_CODE COMBINED_HOURS
40  227555            1 2015-10-02    DOTSUG NDONA          PU      0.0269448
40  227555            3 2015-10-02    DOTSUG NDONA          PU      0.4183320
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using old-school `plyr`, you should be able to do

```
ddply(train, .variables = "DOC_NUM", summarize,
      n_doc_line_num = length(unique(DOC_LINE_NUM)),
      sum_comb_hours = sum(COMBINED_HOURS))
```

The `ddply` function has been replaced by the new `dplyr` package. Using `dplyr`, this would be written:

```
library(dplyr)
train %>% group_by(DOC_NUM) %>%
    summarize(n_doc_line_num = n_distinct(DOC_LINE_NUM),
              sum_comb_hours = sum(COMBINED_HOURS))
```

I assumed that by "a COUNT of the column called DOC_LINE_NUM" you mean the count of distinct values.

If you share a larger bit of sample data (preferably with `dput`, say `dput(droplevels(head(train, 10)))` I'd be happy to test to make sure things look good.

Both in `dplyr` and in `plyr::ddply`, `summarize` will drop column that aren't grouping variables. If you want the rest of the columns retained (and they have the **same value** for each value of DOC_NUM) then you can add them to the grouping to retain them. (By "the grouping" I mean `dplyr::group_by` or the `.variables` argument of `plyr::ddply`.)

Comment: "old school" worked great!  Thank you Gregor.  I'll brush up on the new dplyr as suggested as well.

Answer (score 1):

An option using `data.table`.  We converr the 'data.frame' to 'data.table' (`setDT(train)`), grouped by 'DOC_NUM', get the `length` of `unique` elemens of 'DOC_LINE_NUM' (the data.table wrapper for that is `uniqueN`) and the `sum` of 'COMBINED_HOURS'.

```
library(data.table)#v1.9.6+
setDT(train)[,list(n_doc_line_num = uniqueN(DOC_LINE_NUM),
                   sum_comb_hours = sum(COMBINED_HOURS)), 
                                                by = DOC_NUM]
```